# After deploying my project the live pages do not run from GitHub

Tags: reactjs, github

After deploying my project on GitHub the live pages do not run, and it seems both js and css files from the build folder in static are not loaded for some reason, and it shows as a white/blank screen. My project runs perfectly on my localhost.

[image]

I have read and tried many things but it is not working. I am using the master branch as always, I also have the src folder (as I know sometimes it happens for this one to not have been loaded, but it is on gitHub, so this is not the problem).

[This is my repository](https://github.com/Monikitta/robofriends)

I have also attached a screenshot of the error when I try to run the live page from github. It is 404.

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/354577)